# If magic doesn't agree with Muggle technology, how does Arthur Weasley have a flying car that can turn invisible and drive itself?

Tags: harry-potter, technology, vehicles

I don't quite know the extended lore, but I'm pretty sure that it's established that the reason why we don't see modern weapons being used in the series is because magic and Muggle technology just don't agree somehow. Despite this, Arthur Weasley has a flying car that can turn invisible and drive itself. Is this a discrepancy? And if so, is it explained?

Comment: And the Ministry of Magic has cars that can literally squeeze their way forward through traffic without the inside changing shape, IIRC.

Comment: Not to forget the Knight Bus ...